# Как в jq сделать рамки вокруг картинок щёлкая с одним цветом и щёлкая с клав.shift другим?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребят привет, такой вопрос:

Нужно чтоб при щелчке на картинках, вокруг них должна появляться сплошная рамка в 4px.

и в момент щелчка мышью по мотоциклу была зажата клавиша shift,должен стать один цвет , а если не была зажата то цвет рамки должен быть другим.

При повторном щелчке по тому же самому мотоциклу рамка должна исчезать.

вот код ОН НЕ РАБОТАЕТ:

```
$('#div_for_img img').click(function(eventObject) {

    if (eventObject.shiftKey) {
      $(this).css('border', '4px solid #cc0000');
    } else {
      $(this).css('border', '4px solid #333333');
    }
  },
  function() {
    $(this).css('border', 'none');
  });; /*что не так?*/
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста разметку, отформатируйте вопрос: ничего ведь не понятно.

Comment: Что значит - ОН НЕ РАБОТАЕТ?